# Creating a new column from existing columns in a shapefile with a condition in R

Tags: r, attribute-table, sf

I have a shapefile that has multiple columns, and I am trying to merge columns `X5`and`X1` into a new column `class`, such that only the `NA` rows of `X5` get filled by the corresponding rows of `X1`. For example, in the new column the rows `1-4` will have values from rows `1-4` of `X5`, but rows `5-7`will have value `GRND` from column `X1`. Similarly, then rows `8-9` of column `class` will be filled with values `PLSE` from `X5` and so. Hope it makes sense. How can I do this in `R`. I am thinking of using `dplyr` and `ifelse`, but I am stuck.

Sample data

```
FID X1  X5  class
1   VEG PRPU    
2   VEG PRPU    
3   VEG PRPU    
4   VEG PRPU    
5   WTR NA  
6   WTR NA  
7   WTR NA  
8   VEG PLSE    
9   VEG PLSE    
10  GRND NA     
11  GRND NA
```

Code

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

# Load shapefile
shp = st_read("path", "filename")

# Create a new column class
shp %>% add_column(class = NA)

# Try 
shp %>% mutate(class = ifelse(class %in% "", X5, class)) # Stuck...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were really close. You should use `==` instead of `%in%`.

```
shp %>% 
  mutate(class = ifelse(is.na(X5), X1, X5))

#   FID   X1   X5 class
#1    1  VEG PRPU  PRPU
#2    2  VEG PRPU  PRPU
#3    3  VEG PRPU  PRPU
#4    4  VEG PRPU  PRPU
#5    5  WTR        WTR
#6    6  WTR        WTR
#7    7  WTR        WTR
#8    8  VEG PLSE  PLSE
#9    9  VEG PLSE  PLSE
#10  10 GRND       GRND
#11  11 GRND       GRND
```

Comment: I am getting `NA` [values](https://app.box.com/s/uzmuac84sgjnj2v5ohlkdca6lrmtudqd) where there were supposed to be `X1` values in the `class` column.

Comment: Try checking if there are `X5` entries filled with a blank space or something like that. That is probably causing those results.

Comment: Yes you are right thank you, the empty rows shown in `ArcGIS` were actually being shown as `NA` in `R`. So doing, `shp %>% dplyr::mutate(class = ifelse(is.na(X5), X1, X5))` fixes the issue. You can edit that in your answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

If the only issue is to resolve NAs, and you are using `{dplyr}` anyhow, you may consider `dplyr::coalesce()` for a somewhat more concise code.

```
library(dplyr)

shp <- tibble::tribble(~FID, ~X1,  ~X5,  
                       1, 'VEG', 'PRPU',
                       2, 'VEG', 'PRPU',
                       3, 'VEG', 'PRPU',
                       4, 'VEG', 'PRPU',
                       5, 'WTR', NA,  
                       6, 'WTR', NA,  
                       7, 'WTR', NA,  
                       8, 'VEG', 'PLSE',    
                       9, 'VEG', 'PLSE',    
                       10, 'GRND', NA,     
                       11, 'GRND',  NA)


shp %>% 
  mutate(class = coalesce(X5, X1))

     FID X1    X5    class
   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1     1 VEG   PRPU  PRPU 
 2     2 VEG   PRPU  PRPU 
 3     3 VEG   PRPU  PRPU 
 4     4 VEG   PRPU  PRPU 
 5     5 WTR   NA    WTR  
 6     6 WTR   NA    WTR  
 7     7 WTR   NA    WTR  
 8     8 VEG   PLSE  PLSE 
 9     9 VEG   PLSE  PLSE 
10    10 GRND  NA    GRND 
11    11 GRND  NA    GRND
```